# Duplicate a Structure "Section"

Tags: structure

I have a Structure area where there will be 20-24 top level pages for degrees, each with similar (but different) subpages…

- Masters in Accountancy

  - Courses by Year
  - Degree Requirements
  - …etc. x12 or so.
- Masters in Business Administration

  - Courses by Semester
  - Degree Requirements
  - …etc. x12 or so.
- …etc.

It would be super ideal (and save a lot of time) is if I could setup the tree for just on of the degrees, then duplicate it 20 times and use it as a starting point for the others degrees. Has anybody managed to pull something like this off? Guessing I'd have to do it directly in the DB?

(I should mention that because of the variety/flexibility in content around each degree, having a degree channel isn't a good fit for this case. In total, it's much more like a docs section.)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to try hard to avoid making changes directly to the DB if at all possible. It's a good feature idea that isn't built into Craft, so I think a custom plugin might be a good option. It'd be easy enough to build and then you'd have it readily available for other projects in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't touch the DB directly but have you considered doing this via a CSV import? You could setup all your pages right in Excel or OpenOffice or whatever you like and then import the content using [Bob Olde Hampsink's import plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/).

You can setup the hierarchy right in the file using the Title as the Parent entry IIRC (in your case the Course name).  I've used this when importing from other CMSes into Craft and it works great but I'd imagine it'd be pretty handy in this case as well.

Comment: This seems like a great approach, I'll give it a shot.